# Can I have a Samba Domain Controller create a local account on a user's machine on login?

Tags: windows, networking, samba

Our network has a Samba Domain Controller that works fine. However, when a user logs in I want a new profile created on the Windows Machine so that, in the event that the Domain Server is down, the user can still logon to their profile.

So is it possible to have Windows create a new user profile for every network user that logs into the machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Domain users are not local users.

However, I'm not sure why you'd need this - by default, the password hashes for the last 10 domain users to log in to the system are stored locally and used for login if the domain controller is unavailable.

This is configurable through Group Policy or the Local Security Policy.  The setting is "Interactive Logon: Number of previous logons to cache".